# How do I reecho standard input that has been obscured by standard output?

Tags: java, io, console, nonblocking

What I want is an interactive console that can both print out log messages and take in commands at the same time. The terminal version (not the GUI one) of the Minecraft server does what I want to do perfectly.

I almost got my interactive console working with one problem (which happens to deviate this question from other related questions enough to not be a duplicate): when the server logs a message to the console, then whatever is typed into that console would be lost.

To be more specific, the `Log.log` method uses carriage return `\r` to overwrite the current line, which happens to be the same line where commands are typed into the console. While `Log.log` method compensates the overwritten command line by printing the console character `>`, anything that was typed into that console would appear as though it had disappeared. What's even worse is that the `Scanner` variable still holds in the typed command that cannot be modified or deleted by the keyboard.

I want the console to hold whatever was typed into that console and print out log messages at the same time.

### What I've done so far:

I have been working with two classes: `Log` and `Command`. `Log` outputs log messages while the server runs and deals with clients. `Command` interprets commands typed by the admin and evaluates them based on a switch block. While `Log` runs on the main thread, `Command` runs on a separate thread.

#### Sample Output

Let's say I want to start a server. If I want to start it, I would have to type in the command `start` into the console (the server automatically starts itself by default upon launch).

```
[02/01/2015 9:40:19 PM] INFO - Server: version 0.1
> start
```

After pressing the return key, the output should look something like this:

```
[02/01/2015 9:40:19 PM] INFO - Server: version 0.1
[02/01/2015 9:40:35 PM] INFO - Server: Starting server...
[02/01/2015 9:40:40 PM] INFO - Server: Server is now running at localhost:54555
>
```

Now let's say I (mis)type in a command into the console.

```
[02/01/2015 9:40:19 PM] INFO - Server: version 0.1
[02/01/2015 9:40:35 PM] INFO - Server: Starting server...
[02/01/2015 9:40:40 PM] INFO - Server: Server is now running at localhost:54555
> stopp
```

Before I realise that I've made a spelling mistake in typing the `stop` command, the server prints out a log message.

```
[02/01/2015 9:40:19 PM] INFO - Server: version 0.1
[02/01/2015 9:40:35 PM] INFO - Server: Starting server...
[02/01/2015 9:40:40 PM] INFO - Server: Server is now running at localhost:54555
[02/01/2015 9:41:02 PM] INFO - Server: Client connected with username user824294
>
```

As explained above, there's no way of changing the command into something else (or in this case, fix the spelling mistake of the `stop` command).

### Some code:

#### Entry point

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Log.setup();

    // Set log level
    Log.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG);

    Command.setup();

    //setupServer();
    //startServer();
}
```

#### Log.java

```
public class Log {
    public static BufferedWriter writer;

    public static final int VERBOSE = 0;
    public static final int DEBUG = 1;
    public static final int INFO = 2;
    public static final int WARNING = 3;
    public static final int ERROR = 4;

    private static int logLevel = 0;

    private static boolean showedLogLevel = false;

    public static void setup() {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    }

    public static void log(String type, String key, String value) {
        if (!showedLogLevel && logLevel <= VERBOSE) {
            showedLogLevel = true;
            v("Log", "Log level is currently set to verbose.");
            v("Log", "Use Log.setLogLevel method to stop showing verbose messages such as this one.");
            v("Log", "Options (accessed by Log.*): VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR");
        }


        String output = "[" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "] "
                + type + " - "
                + key + ": "
                + value
                + "\n";

        // Since printing the log message would effectively destroy the console cursor, we need
        // to print the console cursor character again on a new line.
        if (Command.consoleCursor) {
            output += Command.consoleCursorCharacter;
        }

        try {
            writer.write("\r");
            writer.write(output);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("FATAL: Unable to log. Exiting...");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void v(String key, String value) {
        if (logLevel > VERBOSE) return;
        log("VERBOSE", key, value);
    }

    public static void d(String key, String value) {
        if (logLevel > DEBUG) return;
        log("DEBUG", key, value);
    }

    public static void i(String key, String value) {
        if (logLevel > INFO) return;
        log("INFO", key, value);
    }

    public static void w(String key, String value) {
        if (logLevel > WARNING) return;
        log("WARNING", key, value);
    }

    public static void e(String key, String value) {
        if (logLevel > ERROR) return;
        log("ERROR", key, value);
    }

    public static void setLogLevel(int _logLevel) {
        logLevel = _logLevel;
    }
}
```

#### Command.java

```
public class Command {
    public static Scanner inputConsole;
    public static boolean consoleCursor = false;
    public static String consoleCursorCharacter = "> ";

    public static void logHelp() {
        String helpStr = "Commands: start, stop, help, exit";
        Log.i("Help", helpStr);
    }

    public static void setup() {
        inputConsole = new Scanner(System.in);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String s;

                while (true) {
                    System.out.print(consoleCursorCharacter);
                    consoleCursor = true;
                    s = inputConsole.nextLine();
                    consoleCursor = false;
                    Command.evaluate(s);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public static void evaluate(String command) {
        String[] arguments = command.split(" ");

        if (arguments[0].isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        switch (arguments[0]) {
            case "start":
                Log.i("Server", "Starting server...");
                // Main.startServer();
                
                break;
            case "stop":
                Log.i("Server", "Stopping server...");
                // Main.stopServer();
                break;
            case "help":
                logHelp();
                break;
            case "exit":
                // Main.stopServer();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("Command", "Invalid command.");
                logHelp();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the sake of those of us unfamiliar with MineCraft, you'll need to explain what it is you want more clearly. What do you mean "lost"? The command doesn't work? What is the behavior you expect?

Comment: Lost as in `Log.log` overwrites (by using carriage return `\r`) over the console line where you type your commands in. I've managed to reprint the console character (`> `) once the a message has been logged, but anything that was typed into the console previously would be overwritten. I want to avoid that happening.

Comment: Then why are you using carriage return rather than linefeed (`\n`)?

Comment: Using linefeed doesn't solve the problem. Yes you can now see what you have typed in previously, but you would have to see a series of console characters `>` in between the log messages.

Comment: related (but not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332179/java-console-application-accepting-commands-from-infinite-loop

Comment: another related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736536/c-input-and-output-to-the-console-window-at-the-same-time

Comment: I think I get what you want now. I've seen this in bash, for example: if you type something while it was printing, what you type will be re-echoed. Can't give you a proper answer, but I believe you have to have direct control over the input buffer to do so. Has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: And here is a link to [the `termios` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termiosl) which is the way this is controlled in C. I think your request is something like the `PENDIN` option there, right?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you for looking into this question. I really appreciate it.  Reechoing upon log output is the essence in this question, as you have pointed out in your comment. As for the threads that I use in my java files, they're essential for concurrently handling both standard input and output. I'm not aware if there is another way of handling nonblocking standard io.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes the PENDIN feature is exactly what I need for my server. I'll use `Scanner` to read in individual characters rather than reading an entire line in order to gain finer control on standard input. The problem now is that printing out the command again, as these reechoed characters cannot be deleted from the console (also there is an aesthetic issue as well, as Intellij IDEA (the IDE I'm using) differentiates stdin from stdout by using a different font colour and style).

Comment: A `Scanner` is built *on top* of standard input, and in fact will not read any input before you press return. The solution, IMO, will have to be at a much lower level, lower than even `Console`. BTW, I suggest you edit your question title to something like "How to re-echo input that has been obscured by output" or something, it may draw others who are more knowledgeable than I.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I found out that even with `InputStream`, the `read` method won't start reading in any characters until the return key has been pressed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it